# Flowbite navbar hamburger not working on chrome browser

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm using flow-bite on my react js project I saw the Navbar hamburger not working (dropdown) on the Chrome browser but the same hamburger is working fine in firefox.
please tell me, How to Solve the Problem.

Answer (score 4):

Several things you need to do:

1. Try downgrading your react app 17.0.2. If your don't know how to then check this [LINK](https://lzomedia.com/blog/how-to-downgrade-from-react-18-to-17-0-2/)
2. Use flowbite CDN script in public index.html

   `<script src="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.4.4/dist/flowbite.js"></script>`

Thats it it will work now. 
Or you can use [flowbite-React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flowbite-react) which is still in development  . Good Luck